# GeoDjango distance of related model

Tags: python, django, postgis, geodjango

I'm trying to return a queryset with distances from a related model.

models.py (simplified)

```
class Store(models.Model):
    geopoint = models.PointField(srid=4326)

    objects = models.GeoManager()


class HashTag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Label(models.Model):
    hashtags = models.ManyToManyField(HashTag)
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)
```

What I need to return are the Label objects which have a certain tag/tags ordered by distance from a given point.

The Labels can be found by:

```
Label.objects.filter(hashtags__in=tags)
```

Distances are available on Store objects calculated with:

```
Store.objects.filter(label__hashtags__in=tags)
             .distance(location).order_by('distance')
```

What I'd like to do is perform a query on the `Label` table to return everything but I suspect this is not possible.

Trying the `distance` method on the queryset results in:

```
TypeError: ST_Distance output only available on GeometryFields.
```

Failing that it would make sense to do the most efficient next best thing. The only solution I can come up with is to perform both queries and merge the results into a set.

Comment: Stumbled across this exactly an year after it was posted! You are doing distance(location) but your field appears to be geopoint. So shouldn't your query be distance('geopoint') ?

Comment: Hey, @RobinElvin, I was wondering, did you found my (quite late) answer helpful?

Comment: @JohnMoutafis Sorry, this project is long gone now so I'm unable to test this against the original issue. If anyone else comments that it works I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible to achieve your query:

- Use the [`annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) to append a distance value on every `Label` object.
- Use the [`Distance()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/functions/#distance) function to calculate the distance between each store's `geopoint` and the `location` point

The query should look like this:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance

Label.objects.filter(hashtags__in=tags)
             .annotate(distance=Distance('store__geopoint', location))
             .order_by('distance')
```